# DOM get image src on click anywhere in div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am able to get the image source when I click on the image...

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('.module img')
    .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", e => {
        console.log(e.target.currentSrc)
    });
```

```html
<div class="module">
    <img src="pics/pic1.jpg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="module">
    <img src="pics/pic2.jpg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="module">
    <img src="pics/pic3.jpg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

...but how can I get the image source no matter where I click in the parent div, without doing event listeners for each child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your solution, it sounds like you will need to get info from either `this`, or the `event` passed into the event listener:

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('.module')
    .forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("click", e => {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.querySelector('img').currentSrc);
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="module">
    <img src="pics/pic.jpg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="usp">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="module">
    <img src="pics/pic2.jpg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="usp">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="module">
    <img src="pics/pic3.jpg">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p class="usp">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.Add a `listener` to the whole `div` with class selector.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".module").forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.children[0].getAttribute('src'))
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <img src="pics/pic.jpg">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p class="usp">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem impsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as it only get's the first div. I wasn't clear enough that there are more than one divs.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the parent, and do **not** use event.stopPropagation()

```
var el = document.querySelector(".module");
el.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
  // Parent div clicked, get the image element ref
  var img = document.querySelector(".module img");
  alert(img.currentSrc)
  // Image src alerted
})
```